# xmlHTTP POST request

Tags: javascript, post, upload, xmlhttprequest

I looked around stackoverflow and on google but didn't find a working solution so far.

I'm trying to send and image file via xmlhttp request to a server. I found this site: https://ptsv2.com/ to test the upload.

I get from the server a 200 - OK back when I send my request, but it shows me also that no files where uploaded (Files: 0)

this is my code:

```
var url = "https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/https://ptsv2.com/t/zuaco-1549007477/post";      

var base64Credentials = btoa(username+":"+password);

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var fd = new FormData();
          /* Add the file */ 
          fd.append("file", "img/1.png");

xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
xhttp.send(fd);

   /* Check the response status */  
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
   {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
      {
         console.log("UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL: " + xhttp.statusText);
         console.log("GET ALL: " + xhttp.getAllResponseHeaders());
      }
      else {
          console.log("UPLOAD FAILED!")
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you cannot set manually a file. Instead use file input element:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var fd = new FormData();
// fd.append("file", "img/1.png");
fd.append("file", document.getElementById('yourInput').files[0]);
```

Comment: The thing is that I get the directory of the image from a server. In the application you push a button, a signal gets send to a server, a camera gets triggered, takes a photo and sends back the path where the image is saved. From there on I have to display the image in the HTML doc and upload it to a server... >.< so I don't have any input fields... can I manipulate this somehow?

Comment: @DeputyDong_ — The the image is on the server, not the client, so you can't upload the file from the client. You need to make the HTTP request from the server (where the file exists and is available to be put in the request)